# Image compression when creating a photo with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I use the Graph API to upload a photo, as below, it works fine. Unfortunately the jpeg image quality on Facebook is significantly worse than the original photo's.

Is there a parameter I can add to maintain the quality?

```
var data = {};
data.url = photo_url;
data.message = "testing 123";
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', data, function (response) {
            console.log('response');
        });
```

Comment: i don´t think there is a parameter.

Comment: I'm also seeing this quality problem with uploaded jpeg images through graph api. Did you find any way around this?